# How to change marquee speed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, marquee

How can I control the speed of a marquee using jQuery? Please suggest the exact attribute/property.

Comment: PLEASE don't use marquees - what information is important enough for your visitor to wait for it to come back when they missed it scrolling past, but not important enough to actually put on the page properly?

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN you can use these attributes:

- `scrollamount`
- `truespeed`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee

Answer (score 0):

`<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left" width="350">`